# Checking page load time of several URL simultaneously

Tags: c#, page-load-time

Can anyone guide me what C# code should I write for getting page load time of each URL if the URLs are given as an input ?

OR

if possible please provide me link to any software that does that. Any software that takes several URL as input and provides the page load time for each URL.

Comment: Please take into account that the results could vary alot: sudden highload on server, your router has high CPU load, etc. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you want to create http://loads.in/ ? O_o

Comment: I just want a code by which I get the "page load time" (as we get in HTTPCheck tool in Internet Explorer) when given several URL as input

Comment: What do you actually want to test? If it's how long webpages take to load have a look at a private instance of Web Page Test (webpagetest.org) this is scriptable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want to measure the time it takes for the first request to be answered, or do you want to include the downloading of style and external scripts and clientside rendering?

The first can simply be solved by using a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

```
WebClient client = new WebClient ();

// Add a user agent header in case the 
// requested URI contains a query.

client.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();

Stream data = client.OpenRead (@"your-url-here");
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (data);
string s = reader.ReadToEnd();

stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);

data.Close();
reader.Close();
```

While for the latter, put a [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) on a form where you create a method for consuming the [DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) event:

```
// in your form declarations
Stopwatch _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
String _url = @"your-url-here";

// in the button-click or whenever you want to start the test
_stopwatch.Start();
this.WebBrowser1.Navigate(_url);

// The DocumentCompled event handler
private void WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Url == _url)
    {  
        _stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", _stopwatch.Elapsed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide me the code as well ? Afterall, its a +100 repo question !!

Comment: actually the first code you have provided is fine but the URLs I m talking about need authentication for their access (I connect to a particular VPN and then open browser with certain credentials to access the URL), I don't think also takes care of that ?

Comment: your second code works fine, but it gives page load time even when page has not loaded successfully !!

Comment: @vaibhav for the first, it should depend on your configuration. `webClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("UserName",
"Password", "Domain");` should work. For the second, try to check if `e.Url` is the URL you're requesting. It will fire for every resource on the page, so images, stylesheets, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

If I am understanding the question correctly, then Apache JMeter could do this: http://jmeter.apache.org/

It is scriptable, and you can set up a variety of scenarios for load testing.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var URLs = new[] 
{ 
    "http://www.google.com", 
    "http://www.microsoft.com", 
    "http://www.slashdot.org"
};

var tasks = URLs.Select(
url => Task.Factory.StartNew(task => 
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var t = (string)task;
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        String result = client.DownloadString(t);
        stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} = {1}", url, stopwatch.Elapsed));
        }
    }, url)
    ).ToArray();
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

With this I get

```
http://www.microsoft.com = 00:00:05.1784172 milliseconds
http://www.slashdot.org = 00:00:09.9922422 milliseconds
http://www.google.com = 00:00:10.8720623 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend YSlow ,is very useful tools for checking  website performance ,[YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure your familiar with the Web debugging proxy [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com).  There is a lot in Fiddler that you will not need (like a UI) for your application, however they provide a .NET library that can be included in your project that will give you all the HTTPness that you could ever want.

> [FiddlerCore](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/fiddlercore) is currently provided as a .NET class library that
>   can be consumed by any .NET application. FiddlerCore is designed for
>   use in special-purpose applications that run with either no
>   user-interface (e.g. test automation), or a UI which is so specialized
>   that a Fiddler Addon would not be a suitable option (e.g. a WPF traffic visualization).

There is a sample app included in the download that I modified in a few minutes that will give you access to the same information shown in the fiddler UI under the statistics tab.  Check Session.Timers object in the fiddlercore dll for these values.

ClientConnected:    15:03:05.017
ClientBeginRequest: 15:03:05.056
ClientDoneRequest:  15:03:05.076
Determine Gateway:  0ms
DNS Lookup:         3ms
TCP/IP Connect: 20ms
HTTPS Handshake:    0ms
ServerConnected:    15:03:05.151
FiddlerBeginRequest:    15:03:05.152
ServerGotRequest:   15:03:05.157
ServerBeginResponse:    15:03:05.292
ServerDoneResponse: 15:03:05.314
ClientBeginResponse:    15:03:05.331
ClientDoneResponse: 15:03:05.333
Overall Elapsed:    00:00:00.2770277

Hope this helps, you will need to figure out how to create your own session instead of using the proxy but that is a stated feature of the product and should not require much time.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want a `Stopwatch`, and either a `WebClient` or a `WebRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this to keep internal web sites active and measure/log response time, kind of a keep alive service:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    LoggingManager.ConfigureAtStartup();

    ErrorLogger.LogInformation("STARTED");

    try
    {
        if (args.Length < 1)
        {
            ErrorLogger.LogInformation("No parameters provided...");
            return;
        }

        int pingTimeoutMilliseconds = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pingTimeoutMilliseconds"]);

        var urls = args[0].Split(';');

        foreach (string url in urls)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
            {
                continue;
            }

            ErrorLogger.LogInformation(String.Format("Pinging url: {0}", url));

            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

                var stopW = new Stopwatch();

                stopW.Start();

                string result = client.DownloadString(url);

                var elapsed = stopW.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                stopW.Stop();

                if (elapsed > pingTimeoutMilliseconds)
                {
                    ErrorLogger.LogWarning(String.Format("{0} - took: {1} milliseconds to answer!", url, elapsed.ToString("N0")));

                    ErrorLogger.LogInformation(String.Format("Response was: {0} chars long", result.Length.ToString("n0")));
                }                        
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        ErrorLogger.LogError(exc);
    }
    finally
    {
        ErrorLogger.LogInformation("COMPLETED");

        LoggingManager.ShutdownOnExit();
    }
}
```

`ErrorLogger` is a little wrapper I made around `Log4Net`.